# REST service does not get POST payload

Tags: wcf, json, rest, service

I have a big problem.
I created a WCF service.My POST declaration looks like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "json/put", 
           Method = "POST", 
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, 
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
string PutData(string jsonText);
```

I was expecting that when I'm sending data (I'm using fiddler2 to test it) that it will automaticly "put" into the jsonText variable.
The service works, but there is no data :(.

Can anybody help? [The whole project](http://www.mediafire.com/?e22osx0m7e62smo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF expects the JSON payload to be deserialized into a type.  Try creating a class that is shaped like your JSON payload and use that as the parameter type.

Comment: Thanks, that was probably it, but it simply started all over again and recoded the following example: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/96404c7a-9130-47b3-9fb1-a3414823f545